# CNN model and bert with text

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, text-classification, bert-language-model

I got error in linear function

```
class MixModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,pre_trained='bert-base-uncased'):
        super().__init__()        
        self.bert =  AutoModel.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')
        self.hidden_size = self.bert.config.hidden_size
        self.conv = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=768, out_channels=256, kernel_size=5, padding='valid', stride=1)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size= 64- 5 + 1)
        
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.3)
        
        self.clf = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size*2,6)
        
        
      
           
    def forward(self,inputs, mask , labels):
        
        cls_hs = self.bert(input_ids=inputs,attention_mask=mask, return_dict= False) 
        x=cls_hs[0]
        print(cls_hs[0]) 
        print(len(cls_hs[0]))
        print(cls_hs[0].size())
        #x = torch.cat(cls_hs,0) # x= [416, 64, 768]
        x = x.permute(0, 2, 1)
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.clf(x)
return x
```

error is

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in linear(input, weight, bias)
   1846     if has_torch_function_variadic(input, weight, bias):
   1847         return handle_torch_function(linear, (input, weight, bias), input, weight, bias=bias)
-> 1848     return torch._C._nn.linear(input, weight, bias)
   1849 
   1850 

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (65536x1 and 1536x6
```

i am trying to concatenate bert model with Cnn 1d using pytorch as disscused here
[output from bert into cnn model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71301279/output-from-bert-into-cnn-model/71304677?noredirect=1#comment126045460_71304677)

Answer (score 0):

```
class MixModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,pre_trained='bert-base-uncased'):
        super().__init__()        
        self.bert =  AutoModel.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')
        self.hidden_size = self.bert.config.hidden_size
        self.conv = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=768, out_channels=256, kernel_size=5, padding='valid', stride=1)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size= 64- 5 + 1)
        
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.3)
        
        self.clf1 = nn.Linear(256,256)
        self.clf2 = nn.Linear(256,6)
```

change linear function